# Excel: Slope/Intercept function with an if condition applied to the X Axis

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, intercept

I'm working on a backend file for another program that, unfortunately, cannot have a graph in it.
That said, I need to generate y axis values for 3 trendlines based on an existing set of data (ignoring zero-values on the Y axis.)
All done with an array formula.
Historical was simple and straightforward.

For the second, I'm trying to limit B's values (date range) to only 2019 dates. I've tried if(year(B:B)=2019). However, this didnt work.
To test the functionality, I tried the if(B:B<>0) and that worked fine.

The first was easy enough, worked fine:

```
=SLOPE(IF($D:$D<>0,$D:$D),$B:$B)*B2+INTERCEPT(IF($D:$D<>0,$D:$D),$B:$B)
```

Any ideas on applying the if(year function to the X axis on both slope and intercept?

Comment: Do you have any input data and expected output, possibly through a screenshot and/or markdown sample data

Comment: What do you have on cell B2?

Comment: Hi JvdV, the input data is: For column B, dates from 1/1/2018 through current, in the M/D/YYYY format. Column D has either a 0 or a decimal value. The IF applied to column D is  necessary to filter out the zero values, as these occur on weekend dates and are necessary for the backend file. However, the 0's should not be factored into the slope or intercept.

Comment: Try: `=SLOPE(IF((YEAR($B:$B)=2019)*($D:$D<>0),$D:$D),IF((YEAR($B:$B)=2019)*($D:$D<>0),$B:$B))*B2+INTERCEPT(IF((YEAR($B:$B)=2019)*($D:$D<>0),$D:$D),IF((YEAR($B:$B)=2019)*($D:$D<>0),$B:$B))`

Comment: Hi Scott,Thanks but this didnt work as an array formula, and gave me an incorrect result (About 30% too low) as a regular formula. 2019 values range from 1.07 to 0.98, but the values generated in this formula range from .74 to .67. Specifically it gave the #Value error

Comment: Then your data is not as you stated.  the formula matches the trend line formula output exactly:  https://imgur.com/Dcv4Ngt

Comment: That may be because the data for year 2019 is between rows ~367-557.  With your formula pasted (and B2 edited to B557, etc), this is the result https://imgur.com/a/pqfu9QQ  as a normal formula. If I use an array, it #Value! errors for all results.  I can still chart the trendline if it skips the 0 values, so that's not an issue, but the calculated points seem to still be factoring in 0. The high point of the trend (.85) is still lower than all my actual data points.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/vlzwwu35ax4gzv7/RMT_Sample.xlsx/file This is a sample file. L_YTD is as a regular formula. L_YTD_Array is as an array formula. Only the regular one seems to be calculating, but it's factoring in the 0's. I'll also need to be able to iferror the formula to generate 0's instead of #VALUE! errors for database integrity.

Comment: Self-bump here, hoping for a solution.